# Magical Record / Core Data: Saving Many Objects (~250K) Without Performance / Time Troubles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having trouble saving (~250k) words (they're inside an array) as objects into Core Data. It takes forever. This is what I'm doing using fast enumeration, once I've created an array with all my words:

```
[self learnWord:word andSave:YES];
```

This saves each word as an object, but it takes forever (~30min).

So instead I tried to just create the objects and saving once after the fast enumeration loop has completed:

```
[self learnWord:word andSave:NO];

//Save our suggestions
 [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

What this does is it checks if an object with a value of "word" doesn't match our word, and creates an entity in such case. Then I assign the following values:

```
wordSuggestion.word = word;
wordSuggestion.popularity = @1;
```

What I've tried doing is disabling SAVE on each individual word and instead I manually save once the fast-enumeration loop is done (This doesn't work).

Is there an easy way to create objects really quickly and save them without taking 30 minutes?

Comment: Have you tried doing the saves in a background thread, via an `NSOperationQueue` with a decent concurrent operation count?

Comment: Thanks for responding @LouisTur, not really sure how to approach NSOperationQueue, any examples you could link to? I'll definitely look it up right now.

Comment: ohh, well I was a bit off @KingPolygon. I had apple's [Core Data and Concurrency](http://bit.ly/coreDconcurrent) guide bookmarked, but now at the top of the guide it says _"Best practices for concurrency with Core Data have changed dramatically since this document was written; please note that this chapter does not represent current recommendations"_. So after panicking for a minute, I found this: [Core Data Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/core-data). Looks like they have some really good iOS8-specific core data info.. I'm going to have to check it out myself

Comment: Thanks @LouisTur! Will def check it out. Appreciate it!

Comment: I don't play with CoreData since our apps all need encryption, but with standard SQLite you need to start a transaction before writing a bunch of data, if you want it to be done this year.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to load 250k items into Core Data on a mobile device may not be the best approach and you should describe why you're trying to do that and consider alternatives.

If you do take this approach then it would be best to create the database in advance and embed it in the app from release. Then, if you need to, only apply a delta update at runtime. In this way the load time doesn't matter.

A load time of 30 minutes is crazy, and presumably you're making a fetch request for each added word (which will be inefficient). Instead you should batch the words into groups (say of 100, but you need to test to find a good value). Run one fetch request for each batch and then create and save the required delta.

Once you have this you can easily create background threads and associated contexts, then when you save those contexts you can save up to yhe parent persistent store. You should ensure that the source word list doesn't contain duplicates when taking this approach).